# What is a performance-critical hotspot and its purpose?

Tags: c#, performance, pointers

I´m reading **C# 5.0 in a Nutshell** (O'Reilly) and in the first chapter there is a section that talks about Memory Management. This sections explains about the the unnecessary usage of pointers in **C#**, because it eliminates the problem of incorrect pointers found in other languages like C++. Finally it mentions the critical usage of pointers in performance-critical hotspots.

Then, what is a **performance-critical hotspot** and its purpose?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

A "performance critical hotspot" refers to a piece of code which is a performance bottleneck. This could be many things, but a good example of this is image processing.

Let's say I have a rather large bitmap and I need to perform some operation on each pixel.  This is going to be a loop with many iterations and perhaps a lot going on.  Saving a bit of CPU and/or IO time during each iteration of this loop (this "hotspot") will result in a large overall performance gain.

So, `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` are out the window.  They're slow and, from experience, I know they will not perform well on large images.  In this case I can use `LockBits` to pin the image to its current memory location and obtain a pointer to the raw image bits.

This sort of traversal will result in *far* faster code and I have now optimized a "performance critical hotspot"